# setDeveloperPayload is Deprecated , any Alternative way for that?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

setDeveloperPayload is Deprecated in Billing Library [2.2.0](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#2-2)

and in Latest release of Billing Library It was Removed this Method in [3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#3-0)

I am using this method from `AcknowledgePurchaseParams`

```
AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
        AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchaseToken)
                .setDeveloperPayload(getPayload()) //<-- "setDeveloperPayload()" deprecated
                .build();
```

Is that any other Alternative way for sending `setDeveloperPayload`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only page I could find with any answers:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/developer-payload

> Developer payload has historically been used for various purposes,
> including fraud prevention and attributing purchases to the correct
> user. With versions 2.2 and higher of the Google Play Billing Library,
> intended use cases that previously relied on developer payload are now
> fully supported in other parts of the library.
>
> With this support in place, we have deprecated developer payload,
> starting with version 2.2 of the Google Play Billing Library. Methods
> associated with developer payload have been deprecated in version 2.2
> and were removed in version 3.0. Note that your app can continue to
> retrieve developer payload for purchases made using either previous
> versions of the library or AIDL.
>
> Use the setObfuscatedAccountId() and setObfuscatedProfileId()
> parameters in BillingFlowParams and retrieve them using the
> getAccountIdentifiers() method in the Purchase object.